# split array nested in json with java

Tags: java, json

I am writing in java

I have a json containing an array, and I am trying to split the array (flattening), each element in the array , should be independent.

I am using `org.json.JSONObject` library for parsing the json (but can use also other class)

**example:**

```
{
  "key": "123456",
  "date": "2018-01-01",
  "users": [
    {"name": "jim", "age": 20},
    {"name": "jack", "age": 21}
  ]
}
```

**result:**

```
[
  {
    "key": "123456",
    "date": "2018-01-01",
    "users": {"name": "jim", "age": 20}

  },
  {
    "key": "123456",
    "date": "2018-01-01",
    "users": {"name": "jack", "age": 21}
  }
]
```

is there any ready  library for that?

**edit:**
I am looking for a solution which is generic, the json could have different fields, and the only thing I know is the path to the arrar (`users` in the example)

Comment: If you require generic solution you should manipulate with raw JSON. For instance using [Java API for JSON Processing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html)

Comment: in general I am using `org.json.JSONObject` for parsing the jsons, to I need to write my own method for the flattening? or is there a ready library for that?

Comment: @dina, yes you should write it yourself, there is no such functionality provided out-of-the-box.

Comment: @JayeshDhandha, you're not reading carefully - the thing you've suggested already done in the answer below the post (using different library). Author is not interested with conversions using POJOs.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using almost any available JSON parsing library. For example I will do it with [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson). You most probably already have data classes (POJOs) for your entries. That's my view of such hierarchy

`BaseDataView` represents common fields

```
import java.util.Date;

public abstract class BaseDataView {
    protected String key;
    protected Date date;

    // public get/set
}
```

`OldDataView` represents your old view

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class OldDataView extends BaseDataView {
    private List<User> users;

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Data [key=" + key + ", date=" + date + ", users=" + users + "]";
    }

    public List<NewDataView> toNewData() {
        if (users != null && !users.isEmpty()) {
            return users.stream().map(u -> new NewDataView(key, date, u))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        } else {
            return Collections.singletonList(new NewDataView(key, date, null));
        }
    }
}
```

`NewDataView` represents our new view

```
import java.util.Date;

public class NewDataView extends BaseDataView {
    private User users;

    public NewDataView() {
        super();
    }

    public NewDataView(String key, Date date, User users) {
        super();
        this.key = key;
        this.date = date;
        this.users = users;
    }

    public User getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(User users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "NewData [key=" + key + ", date=" + date + ", users=" + users + "]";
    }
}
```

And the main class which will read value, convert it and write to string.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class StackExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"));

        String input = "{\"key\": \"123456\",\"date\": \"2018-01-01\",\"users\":" 
            + " [{\"name\": \"jim\", \"age\": 20},{\"name\": \"jack\", \"age\": 21}]}";
        OldDataView d = mapper.readValue(input, OldDataView.class);
        List<NewDataView> nd = d.toNewData();
        String ret = mapper.writeValueAsString(nd);
        System.out.println(ret);
    }
}
```

This will generate desired result. For sure, you can get rid of `NewDataView` class if you are ok will additional [] bracers in `users` field in your JSON representation. You also can use various annotations to customize your format.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

here is the method I wrote:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public static JSONArray parse(JSONObject json, String key) {
    JSONArray flattenedJson = new JSONArray();
    JSONArray arr = json.getJSONArray(key);
    json.remove(key);
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++){
        JSONObject jscopy = new JSONObject(json.toString()); // cloning the json
        jscopy.put(key, arr.get(i));
        flattenedJson.put(jscopy);
    }
    return flattenedJson;
}
```

using it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String jsonStr = "{key: 12345 ,date: '2018-01-01', users: [{name: jim, age: 20},{name: jack, age: 21}]}";
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
    JSONArray flattenedJson =  parse(json, "users");
    System.out.println(flattenedJson.toString());

}
```

output:

```
➜  [{"date":"2018-01-01","key":12345,"users":{"name":"jim","age":20}},
    {"date":"2018-01-01","key":12345,"users":{"name":"jack","age":21}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a manual parsing for your flatten requirement. I have some improvements to suggest on the `parse` method in your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49752531/2438951).

Instead of

```
JSONObject jscopy = new JSONObject(json.toString()); // cloning the json
```

For cloning the array stripped json, use below:

```
JSONObject jscopy = new JSONObject(json, JSONObject.getNames(json));
```

This will be faster and will avoid a serialize/deserialize (in json terms).
You may also evaluate the `JSONObject.getNames(json)` part before and outside of the for loop, and just use the evaluated `String[]` inside the loop.